# Material design app bar with different colorsfor different activities

Tags: android, material-design

Is it possible to style your action bar along with notification bar with different colors for different activities in a single app. If I create a theme using styles.XML I get single color all over different activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare different styles for different activities in Android Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".RedActivity"
        android:label="RedActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyRedTheme" />

    <activity
        android:name=".BlueActivity"
        android:label="BlueActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyBlueTheme"/>
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much. Searched the net and found different difficult solutions. But yours is the best

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correct, you want different action bars for different activities?

Yes, you would need to create some action bars and edit the styles there. Once done that make sure for each activity you have specified which action bar to you.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main1, menu);
    return true;
}
```

But if you are trying to say can you change the single action bar with different activities then just go to the manifest and edit it there

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/syle1" />
```